# Adding Delay between inserting data in row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am recieving data (10 records at a time) and inserting it in a div in a javascript loop

```
    var a1 = $('.HomeAnnoucement').length;
            var a2 = $('.HomeAnnoucement').length;
            for (a1 ; a1 < (+a2 + +data.d.length) ; a1++) {

                var a = a1 - a2;
                var newFormat = '<div class="HomeAnnoucement"><label class="annID" id="archannouncementID' + a1 + '" style="display: none;" /><div class="DateandDelete left"><a class="AnnoucementDate left"><strong>' + data.d[a].EffectiveDate.split('/')[1] + getPostWord(parseInt(data.d[a].EffectiveDate.split('/')[1])) + '</strong> ' + getMonthString(parseInt(data.d[a].EffectiveDate.split('/')[0])) + '</a><div class="clear"></div></div><a class="AnnoucementTitle left"><strong id="archannTitle' + a1 + '" class="bold"></strong></a><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="AnnoucementDescription" id="archannDescription' + a1 + '" style="display:none;"></div>';
                $('#archivedAnnouncements').append(newFormat);
                $('#archannouncementID' + a1).append(data.d[a].ID);
                $('#archannTitle' + a1).append(data.d[a].Title);
                if (data.d[a].Owner != "" && data.d[a].Owner != " ") {
                    $('#archannTitle' + a1).append('<label style="font-weight: normal !important;">&nbsp; by ' + data.d[a].Owner + '</label>');
                }
                var description = data.d[a].Description.replace(/\"/g, "'");
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.innerHTML = description;
                var descriptiontext = div.textContent || div.innerText || "";
                $('#archannDescription' + a1).html(data.d[a].Description);
            }
```

I want to add delay in between inserting the rows. So that the user could see each record insertion in the grid. I have tried inserting the elements with display: none and fadingIn setTimeOut function but that didnt work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JQuery Show with animation](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Here is sample quoted form page above

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
      p { background:yellow; }
      </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Show it</button>

      <p style="display: none">Hello  2</p>
<script>
    $("button").click(function () {
    $("p").show("slow");
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

In this case you can add hidden controls to child list, and call show with animation in loop

Comment: well i tried that too, but it seems like all 10 records get shown at once.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery .delay() would help you

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your existing code to hide each row and then set a delay and fadeIn...

```
var a1 = $('.HomeAnnoucement').length;
var a2 = $('.HomeAnnoucement').length;
for (a1 ; a1 < (+a2 + +data.d.length) ; a1++) {

    var a = a1 - a2;
    var $newFormat = $('<div class="HomeAnnoucement"><label class="annID" id="archannouncementID' + a1 + '" style="display: none;" /><div class="DateandDelete left"><a class="AnnoucementDate left"><strong>' + data.d[a].EffectiveDate.split('/')[1] + getPostWord(parseInt(data.d[a].EffectiveDate.split('/')[1])) + '</strong> ' + getMonthString(parseInt(data.d[a].EffectiveDate.split('/')[0])) + '</a><div class="clear"></div></div><a class="AnnoucementTitle left"><strong id="archannTitle' + a1 + '" class="bold"></strong></a><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="AnnoucementDescription" id="archannDescription' + a1 + '" style="display:none;"></div>');
    $('#archivedAnnouncements').append($newFormat);
    $('#archannouncementID' + a1).append(data.d[a].ID);
    $('#archannTitle' + a1).append(data.d[a].Title);
    if (data.d[a].Owner != "" && data.d[a].Owner != " ") {
        $('#archannTitle' + a1).append('<label style="font-weight: normal !important;">&nbsp; by ' + data.d[a].Owner + '</label>');
    }
    var description = data.d[a].Description.replace(/\"/g, "'");
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = description;
    var descriptiontext = div.textContent || div.innerText || "";
    $('#archannDescription' + a1).html(data.d[a].Description);
    $newFormat.hide().delay(a * 500).fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: It should work, but it didnt. I tried a similar thing with delay but delay doesnt seem to work here. All 10 records get shown at one.